# Windows desktop screen sharing for Android via Wi-Fi

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, remote-control

How do I share desktop screen on Android, and control my Desktop PC through Android?

**UPDATE based on OP's comments (geffchang):** `How do I program this? Which libraries can I use for this? I want to make my own server for this.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TeamViewer for Remote Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile&hl=en) for this. Download the app for your phone from the link and download the software for your PC from http://www.teamviewer.com

On screen tips will show you how to proceed with remote sharing.

Both the devices must be connected to WiFi.

Comment: please tell me how i program it ? which library me use for this? i want to make my own server for this.

Comment: @unzila, You **cannot program** this software. All you can do is to use this as-is. If you are looking for a highly customizable software, you may not find a good one.

Comment: yes but i m beginner in android development and i want to make screen sharing app , for this i need help nd guide lines.

Comment: @unzila You can always try our sister site [so] for your development related questions.